# What do you call a thread's "ancestry"?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

Let's say I have this:

```java
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(Foo::a).start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    static void a() {
        new Thread(Foo::b).start();
    }
    static void b() {
        new Thread(Foo::c).start();
    }
    static void c() {
        System.out.println("Blah blah blah");
    }
}
```

the thread that started `a` came from `main`, the thread that started `b` came from `a`, the thread that started `c` came from `b`.

Is there a common term to describe how a thread came to existence, e.g., main->a->b->this thread? (In the language agnostic sense.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I guess I'm thinking more language agnostic than just java. I'll update this.

Comment: I think _ancestry_ is an appropriate term.

Comment: I suspect you need to invent your own terminology – keep it simple and make it clear to your readers. I agree that ‘ancestry’ is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX *process* is like a thread that has a private memory space, so terminology used for processes might be appropriate. In the POSIX (Unix) world, the relationship between processes is described as *parent* and *child*. If process *A* creates process *B*, *A* is the parent of *B*, and *B* is the child of *A*.

Although more distant relationships are possible, they are not often specially named in the POSIX world, but clearly a term like *parentage* or *ancestry* (as suggested by a commentator) would be appropriate.